# Send UDP Datagrams using Python

Tags: python, numpy, sockets, struct

I want to send a data request over udp using the socket API. The format of the request is as follows:

```
ID | Data_Length | Data
```

The request contains the following parameters :An Identifier (ID), (Data_Length) is the size of (Data) and (Data) which is the data to be sent, (Data) has a variable size.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
def send_request():
    request_format="bbs" # 1 Byte for the ID 1 Byte for Data_Length and s for data
    data_buff=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) # Data to be sent
    msg = struct.pack(request_format,0x01,0x09,data_buff.tobytes())
    print("msg = ", msg)
    s0.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    s0.sendto(msg, (UDP_BC_IP, UDP_SERVER_PORT))
```

My questions:

1- Using Wireshark I can see that only the 1st Byte of Data has been sent why ?[image]

2- The output of the print instruction is `msg =  b'\x01\t\x01'` why did I get this output, I was waiting for something similar to `[0x01,0x09,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `dtype` of `data_buff` - it is `int64` unless you use:

```
data_buff = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then repeat your `s` specifier according to the size of the array:

```
request_format="bb" + str(data_buff.size) + "s"
```

Now you can pack with:

```
msg = struct.pack(request_format,0x01,0x09,data_buff.tobytes())
```

and your message will look like this:

```
b'\x01\t\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t'
```

The TAB character is ASCII code 9, so you will see `\t` where your data is 9.